# Custom Table that joins fields back to master table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table below that stores which table/fields are required to have a value to meet Eligibility.

Basically Client.Field1 has to contain a value of 1, Client.Field2 a value of 2, etc.

Does anyone know how I return True if all the values match within the Client table or False if the values don't match in the Client table, and it be flexible enough that if an extra field was added it would be picked up?

```
CREATE TABLE [CustomField](
    [CustomFieldID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldTable] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [EligibilityValue] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomField] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomFieldID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO
INSERT [CustomField] ([CustomFieldID], [FieldTable], [FieldName], [EligibilityValue]) VALUES (119, N'Client', N'Field1', 1)
GO
INSERT [CustomField] ([CustomFieldID], [FieldTable], [FieldName], [EligibilityValue]) VALUES (120, N'Client', N'Field2', 2)
GO
INSERT [CustomField] ([CustomFieldID], [FieldTable], [FieldName], [EligibilityValue]) VALUES (130, N'Client', N'Field3', 1)
GO
INSERT [CustomField] ([CustomFieldID], [FieldTable], [FieldName], [EligibilityValue]) VALUES (141, N'Client', N'Field4', 2)
GO

CREATE TABLE Client
(
    ClientID int,
    Field1 int,
    Field2 int,
    Field3 int,
    Field4 int
)

--this would return True when the comparison is done
insert into Client
(
    ClientID,
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    Field4
)
values
(
    100,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    2
)

--this would return False when the comparison is done
insert into Client
(
    ClientID,
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    Field4
)
values
(
    101,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to convert multiple rows of table `customfield` to a single row, so that you can easily compare it with your `Client` table.

You can write your query like following using `CTE` and `PIVOT`.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [field1], 
                [field2], 
                [field3], 
                [field4] 
         FROM   (SELECT fieldtable, 
                        fieldname, 
                        eligibilityvalue 
                 FROM   customfield) AS SourceTable 
                PIVOT ( Max(eligibilityvalue) 
                      FOR fieldname IN ([Field1], 
                                        [Field2], 
                                        [Field3], 
                                        [Field4]) ) AS pivottable) 
SELECT c.*, 
       COALESCE(O.found, 'Not Found') AS Found 
FROM   client C 
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT 'Found' Found 
                    FROM   cte CT 
                    WHERE  CT.field1 = c.field1 
                           AND CT.field2 = c.field2 
                           AND CT.field3 = c.field3 
                           AND CT.field4 = c.field4) O
```

**Output**

```
ClientID    Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Found
100          1       2       1        2     Found
101          1       2       2        2     Not Found
```

**[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/KNOY75750)**

**Note:** Instead of using `OUTER APPLY`, you can also use sub queries.

**EDIT**:

To make it dynamic, you you need to write a dynamic query using `PIVOT` like following.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename([FieldName]) 
         FROM   CustomField
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @sqltext VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sqltext = ISNULL(@sqltext,'')  + 'CT.' + C.[FieldName]  + ' = ' + 'C.' + C.[FieldName] + ' AND '  +  CHAR(10)
  FROM CustomField c
  --Append Ending Condition
SET @sqltext = @sqltext + ' 1=1'



DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) ='
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ' + @cols + '    

     FROM  
    (SELECT FieldTable, FieldName, EligibilityValue   
        FROM CustomField) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT  
    (  
    max(EligibilityValue)  
    FOR FieldName IN (' + @cols + ')  
    ) AS PivotTable  

)
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(O.Found,''Not Found'') as Found FROM Client C
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT ''Found'' Found FROM CTE CT where ' +  @sqltext + '
) O'

EXEC (@query)
```

**[Online Demo for Dynamic Query](https://rextester.com/BCR72151)**

Comment: Thanks @PSK, the problem is though how do you make it dynamic as an extra field could be added to the CustomField table?

Comment: In that scenario you need to make it dynamic pivot using dynamic query and your select should also be dynamic. Converting above query to dynamic should be easy

Comment: @Philip, I have included the dynamic version of the query, now you don't have to worry about the no of columns, you might require to put where condition in the CustomField if it hold values of other tables also like  [FieldTable]='Client'

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `EXCEPT`. For example:

```
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE ClientID = 100
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE ClientID = 101
)
BEGIN;
    SELECT 'not equal'
END;
```